# Using Ajax on a webApp

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on an application and I would like to use Ajax to partially render part of web page instead of full post back. So I use `scriptManager` and `updatepanel` but I have an error in JS `sys is not defined`. I took a look in generated JS code and it seems that no Ajax client side framework has been loaded by scriptmanager, no reference at scriptressource.

I created a website by using vs2010 template to test ajax and all works fine but in `web.config` I don't found any difference. Is it a known problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

After comment and uncomment different part of my code i found that is my objectdatasource which cause the problem... ObjectDataSource use function instance to retrieve business object but since i use class properties as argument of my "select" objectdatasource function i need to define current instance of my page as object instance (1) but when work is finished is also disposed by objectdatasource .... :) i stop disposing process by using event "ObjectDisposing" (2) ...

(1)

```
protected void OdsRecordObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
        {
            e.ObjectInstance = this;
        }
```

(2)

```
protected void OdsRecordObjectDisposing(object sender, ObjectDataSourceDisposingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

bye !